# Why is jQuery Flipcounter conflicting in Magento?

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

I am trying to add the `flipcounter` to the home page of [my Magento site](https://skribbies.com/) from [here](http://bloggingsquared.com/jquery/flipcounter).

After adding the following scripts, the newsletter button in the footer won't work.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.flipCounter.1.2.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have tried adding using following in `jquery.flipCounter.1.2.pack.js`, but still doesn't work:

```
(function($) { 
  $(function() {
    // more code using $ as alias to jQuery
  });
})(jQuery);
// other code using $ as an alias to the other library
```

I noticed Magento already has jQuery 1.8.2, so do I still need to add jQuery 1.6.2?

Comment: Check console in your firebug I add a comment try to add $('.vid_trigger').click( function(e){  in ready function and let me know it done.It's create bug in console $()is null.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this jQuery in ready function its giving error in console I hope it fixed your issue.

```
$('.vid_trigger').click( function(e){

            e.preventDefault();
            $( "#showSlideshowVideo" ).remove();
            var URL = $(this).attr('videoLink');
            var htm = '<iframe width="640" height="360" style="width:640px;height:360px;" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + URL + '?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen ></iframe>';

                $('#lightVideoBox').append(htm);

            return false;
        });
```

Comment: hello, this code is not for the counter, the and it's already under  jQuery in ready function, i think the reason it's giving an error is because, the element with class "vid_trigger" is missing on the page.

Comment: if you look at the flipcounter link, then you can see the code for flipcounter in step 3 & 5.

Answer (score 0):

You need to begin the script with jQuery.noConflict(); and change the '$'s to 'jQuery's or else the script wont play nicely with the native Prototype framework.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function(jQuery) { 
   jQuery(function() {
   // ... No $s
   });
})(jQuery);
// ... No $s
```

As for the jQuery library, I think Magento only calls it on specific pages for specific functions — like the image zoom if enabled. You will therefore need to call the jQuery library into your home page. Best practice would be to add the following to your local.xml ...

```
<cms_index_index><!-- Handle pinpoints the home page -->
   <reference name="head"><!-- Identifies the head block -->
      <action method="addItem">
         <type>skin_js</type>
         <name>js/jquery.min.js</name><!-- specify your library location and file name within skin/js -->
      </action>
   </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

You can always use the layout updates for the page in CMS Page Management by entering the same XML but leave out the  layout handle.